# GitHub Won't Load Jupyter Notebook Dynamic Content

Tags: python, html, css, github, jupyter-notebook

I want to have slideshows with buttons to flip through images on my Jupyter Notebook analysis, but GitHub doesn't render the buttons, and only shows one image in the slideshow when I run code like this. It works fine on my Jupyter Notebook on my PC.

Is there a different service or something that I can add to my GitHub to make dynamic content like a slideshow with buttons show up?

Thank you.

Comment: In short, GitHub's rendering of notebooks is only ever a quick, rough preview for coders. It has a lot of issues still even though it has come quite a ways in the last few years. [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) generally offers a much more full-featured experience for rendering 'static' `.ipynb` files. However, you are trying to view HTML made by RISE, I assume? Like [here](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE#rise)? Is there additional stuff that you need to do? Maybe. I cannot tell because you didn't share what you are doing or a link. If it relies on active coding, you need to use ....

Comment: <continued> MyBinder to share it with active Python. If it it is just meant to be static, like show previously made results as `.png` as your post indicates then you can maybe do it it more easily by making a reveal.js presentation that you share via GitHub Pages since MyBinder is often 'busy' lately as it is used by many people and there are limited resources.

Comment: I forgot to complete my nbviewer mention. You basically point nbviewer at Jupyter notebooks online & it will render them. It can handle javascript-based examples, & so it isn't completely 'static'. Example: scroll down [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/rj180492/Python/blob/main/Covid-19%20Impacts%20Analysis%20using%20Python.ipynb) to see Plotly plots that are still interactive as rendered by nbviewer. Or [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/Plotly3d-scatter-plots.ipynb). The URL pattern for GitHub is standard so you can make the links yourself.

Comment: You probably can see an example of MyBinder showing a notebook as a slideshow [by clicking here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/damianavila/RISE/master?filepath=examples%2FREADME.ipynb). (Be patient and maybe try it again later if isn't working the first time.) That comes from [here](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE), specifically it is launching [this notebook](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/blob/master/examples/README.ipynb), triggered via the URL. It autolaunches in presentation mode because you can see `autolaunch": true,` in metadata towards the bottom ...

Comment: <continued> of the code [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/damianavila/RISE/master/examples/README.ipynb). It is very similar to what is described [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-rise#creating-interactive-presentations-on-binder-with-rise), although you'll note the syntax has changed slightly since that last link was written up. It is now `rise": {` whereas it used to be `"livereveal": {`. You can use the [mybinder site](https://mybinder.org/) for building the URL to point at a repo, but you probably need to edit it by hand to match the example URL I supplied.